# htaccess mod rewrite "/" to "?"

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

dumb godaddy changed something and now my full url for my CMS doesn't work.

I need to change my URLs from:

http://www.mywebsite.com/blog/view.php/2013/07/05/story.html

**http://www.mywebsite.com/blog/view.php/**

to

http://www.mywebsite.com/blog/view.php?2013/07/05/story.html

**http://www.mywebsite.com/blog/view.php?**

?? Any help would be great!!

Thanks!!

EDIT :

Here is my current .htaccess page:

```
addhandler x-httpd-php-cgi .php4
addhandler x-httpd-php5-cgi .php5
addhandler x-httpd-php5-cgi .php


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mywebsite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mywebsite.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Redirecting to `view.php?` doesn't make sense. The `?` would get dropped because there's on query string following it. Did you mean `view.php?/`?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /view\.php/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?/view\.php)/(.*)$ $1?$2 [NC,QSA,L]
```

Comment: not working when I go to http://www.mywebsite.com/blog/view.php/2013/07/05/story.html it isn't rewriting to http://www.mywebsite.com/blog/view.php?2013/07/05/story.html